# Does a DCL Fonts Reference Exist?

Tags: autolisp

I'm was going reviewing a few `autolisp` and `dcl` tutorials ([afralisp](https://www.afralisp.net/dialog-control-language/tutorials/getting-started-part-2.php) & [autolisp-exchange](https://autolisp-exchange.com/Tutorials/MyDialogs.htm)) to brush up on the `dcl` code. To cut to the question, I see that the text can be underlined by the `mnemonic` in [afralisp](https://www.afralisp.net/dialog-control-language/tutorials/getting-started-part-2.php) and the `&` in [autolisp-exchange](https://autolisp-exchange.com/Tutorials/MyDialogs.htm).

- Is there a better way to underline a string of characters?
- Can a string be made bold, italicized, or strike-though with this
  file type?
- If the above is true, is there a reference webpage that has a list of fonts that can be used with the `dcl` file type?

This webpage may contain the solution, but I haven't seen how: [AutoDesk.com](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ffa23ce210c4a30acaf-63b9.htm,topicNumber=d0e123454)

Comment: The [`dcl`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dcl/info) tag applies to Digital Command Language questions. There does not appear to be a suitable tag for AutoLISP Dialog Control Language questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you cannot arbitrarily change the GUI font face or style using standard DCL.

The ability to underline text is purely an exploit of the `mnemonic` property which allows DCL controls to be manipulated using keys on the keyboard which correspond to the underlined letters as opposed to using the mouse to click such controls.

Whilst DCL text has the `is_bold` property, this has never worked (and likely never will). One alternative is to feign bold text using the `set_tile` function in conjunction with an `image` tile; or you can use the `fixed_width_font` property, but, as the name implies, this will change the text to use a fixed width font (the exact font cannot be changed).

One other possibility is to display text using the `vector_image` function applied to an `image` tile, as I demonstrate in the 'About' dialog for my [Incremental Numbering Suite](http://lee-mac.com/numinc.html) application.